# Concatenate nested same key values in sub objects in python dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I have this python dictionary that contains inside some nested objects:

**Input**

```
 {
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "default",
                    "type": "pkg"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name1",
                    "subobj": [
                        {
                            "name": "subname1",
                            "subobj": [
                                {
                                    "name": "sub-subname1",
                                    "type": "pkg"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "sub-subname2",
                                    "type": "pkg"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "folder"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "folder"
                }
            ]
}
```

I need to recursively create a list that concatenates the "name" keys (maintaining the hierarchy) like the following:

**Output**

- default
- name1/subname1/sub-subname1
- name1/subname1/sub-subname2

   
  **How Could I achieve this Output taking in consideration that could be there infinite nested object in subobj ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a rather simple recursive function, building up a `prefix` string of parent names and finally yielding the combined names for all the `pkg` items.

```
def get_names(lst, prefix=""):
    for d in lst:
        if d["type"] == "pkg":
            yield f"{prefix}{d['name']}"
        elif d["type"] == "folder":
            yield from get_names(d["subobj"], f"{prefix}{d['name']}/")
```

Then call this for the `data["data"]` item (`data` being your full nested dictionary):

```
for name in get_names(data["data"]):
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
default
name1/subname1/sub-subname1
name1/subname1/sub-subname2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this function should make the job

```py
from typing import Union

def get_values(obj, only_add: str, prev_key: str = '') -> list:
    keys = []
    if type(obj) is dict:
        for key, item in obj.items():
            if key == only_add:
                keys.append(f"{prev_key}/{item}")
                prev_key = f"{prev_key}/{item}"
                
            elif isinstance(item, (list, dict)):
                keys.extend(get_values(item, only_add, prev_key))
    
    elif type(obj) is list:
        for item in obj:
            keys.extend(get_values(item, only_add, prev_key))
    return keys
```

Output of the function on your data

```
get_values(data, only_add="name")
>>> ['/default',
 '/name1',
 '/name1/subname1',
 '/name1/subname1/sub-subname1',
 '/name1/subname1/sub-subname2']
```

Comment: Not quite, i just need the "name" keys' values :-)

Comment: Have you read the output requested ?
@Bass asked for 
>>> ["/default",
 "/name1/subname1/sub-subname1",
 '/name1/subname1/sub-subname2",
 ]

not
>>> ['/data/name --> default', 
 '/data/name --> name1',
 '/data/subobj/name --> subname1',
 '/data/subobj/subobj/name --> sub-subname1',
 '/data/subobj/subobj/name --> sub-subname2']
 '/data/subobj/subobj/name --> sub-subname2']

Comment: This combines all the _direct_ parent keys, but OP wants to combine all the `name` values in the parent dicts.

Comment: Also, did not check in detail, but why the instanceof check after the type checks? You already have cases for all types on the top level, so can't you just call the function again for all children?

Comment: @tobias_k, thank for your comments. I really misunderstood the question. I have finally corrected my answer. Thanks again

Comment: @Fedeco thank for your comments. I really misunderstood the question.